# writing text in textfile and saving it using saveDialog

Tags: java, string, save

I want to write a string in a text file which should be dynamically saved by the save dialog.
I have done this task statically, meaning the file with the specified file name is created and text is also written from `JTextArea`.  I want to save this file on my given location and with my given name.  Can you please guide me in this regard?

```
do{
    String fileData=jTextArea1.getText();
    byte buf[]=fileData.getBytes();

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text/fasta files", ".txt", ".fasta");
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("inside try after retVal");
                    try{
                        //OutputStream f2=new FileOutputStream("filename.txt");
                        OutputStream f2=new FileOutputStream("file.txt");

                        f2.write(buf);
                        f2.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(CreatingFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                                }


                } else {
                    return null;
                } //else ends


    // TODO add your handling code here:
}while(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use chooser.getSelectedFile()

Use a FileWriter, wrapped in a BufferedWriter, not a FileOutputStream.

And use the write(...) method of JTextArea to write out the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
new FileOutputStream(chooser.getName());
```

instead of

```
new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
```